# Adding a role to every user in discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My Question is straightforwarded, i already searched for it everywhere on the Internet but couldn't find anything. I want my bot to give a role, here the role is named "banned", to every single user. I already tried it using this code:

```
@client.command()
async def role(ctx):
    try:
        for member in ctx.guild.members:
            await member.add_roles("banned")
    except:
        print("Can't add the Roles!")
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you share what error are you getting?

Comment: Is your runtime printing `Can't add the Roles!` ? If so, you may be masking the true error. You can always give the exception an alias with `except ex` and then `print(ex)` to see the actual error.

Comment: @h0r53 when i use `except Exception as e: ` it prints `'str' object has no attribute 'id'`

Comment: Just a guess, `.add_roles()`expects an object argument and not a string.

Comment: Check this post for an example of adding roles: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43433296/how-to-use-the-add-roles-method-from-the-python-discord-api

Answer (score 0):

Found an working answer.

```
@client.command()
async def role(ctx):
    try:
        banned_role = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name="banned")
        for member in ctx.guild.members:
            await member.add_roles(banned_role)
    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
```